# Selecting a range from bottom to top in Excel?

Tags: excel

Let's say I need to select a range in Excel from A2 to A1,(if I'm inserting something, it needs to insert to a2 first).

No matter which direction I choose, Excel automatically chooses `Sheet1!$A$1:$A$2`. I tried to even manually change it to `Sheet1!$A$2:$A$1` but that didn't work.

How can I either disable this automatic selection or how to choose a range from bottom to top?

Comment: Can you generate your sequence "the other way around"?

Comment: why do you need to do this? I don't think you can change this default behavoir, but there may be other tricks to do what you want, if you can provide what you are ultimately trying to get at

Comment: Even if you could do this it wouldn't change the order Excel processes any operation on the selection.  Without knowing what you're trying to do it's hard to say for sure but this is unlikely to solve whatever issue you're experiencing.

Comment: I need this for a algorithm Im following in xcelsius, the alternative way would selecting a range, a1 and b2 or a1 and b3 diagonally, is there any macro I can use to choose lets say a1 and b3?

Comment: In Excel ranges are always normalized. There is no difference between $A$1:$A$2 and $A$2:$A$1.

Answer (score 0):

The real alternative would seem to be not to insert into A2 before inserting into A1 but to insert into A2 first and then keep inserting into A2, with Shift cells down.

Answer (score -1):

From bottom to top you have to select range from bottom, like I did in my `countif` formula:

```
=COUNTIF($AA$8:AA8,AA8)
```

I locked AA8 cell and made it range with same cell because there were no other rows above the current row. And criteria was again this cell so I got my result.